# Is it possible to use spaces in Lion the same way as in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Is it possible to use spaces in Lion the same way as in Snow Leopard?

I'm thinking about upgrading but I love spaces... the keyboard shortcuts... the grid pattern... I'm wondering if that is all there still or if I must use this "mission control" thing?

- Are the keyboard shortcuts still there?
- Can I still get it to use the grid pattern? (i.e. 2x2 or 3x3)
- Can Spaces still be configured to pop up when you move to a corner of the screen with your mouse?

Comment: It's just called Lion, no snow

Comment: There is no actual animal called Snow Lion.

Comment: must have been an editing typo... but snow lions would look cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single line of spaces, and they integrate with applications in full screen mode. So when you make e.g. QuickTime Player full screen, it will get its own space. In the screenshots, you see iTunes, Mail, and an RSS reader each on their own space.

Spaces are easier to create and remove, as this has been integrated in the space switching view.

[image: Adding spaces]

[image: Removing spaces]

---

You can assign keyboard shortcuts for moving between spaces and to a specific space in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Mission Control*.

[image]

You can also define hot corners and their actions in *System Preferences » Mission Control*.

[image]

[image]

The available items for the hot corners are the following:

[image]

---

In essence, the basic functionality is still there, but only with a single row of desktops, and a different presentation than with the previous Exposé.

Comment: great.. understand better now, thanks for the screenshots - they really help

Comment: Nevertheless it should be mentioned, that Mission Control does not provide all the features like Spaced does/did. The one thing that I really miss hard, is the possibility to drag and drop single applications between the spaces (in Mission Control we have to switch to the space, where the app is running and than drag it to another space). Also it behaves kind of weird when you are using a second screen. For example, it is not possible to drag a window from one screen on a different space on the second screen. So reorganizing applications in Mission Control is implemented very poorly imho.